# iOS App UIView rotating, content is not

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently building an iOS app, and the only supported orientations are landscape left and right. I've specified this in several ways:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation); //iOS 5 compatibility.
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; //iOS 6
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

And I've specified the supported orientations as only the landscape ones in the app's Info.plist. When I run the app on my device (or even in the simulator), I know that the root view is in landscape orientation (switcher is on the long side of the screen, as is notification center), however the content still originates from the top left corner of the screen, as if in portrait mode, not the bottom left or top right, like I want it to be. I have no idea what could be causing the content not to rotate with the parent view, as this code worked on iOS 5, but is not on iOS 6.

EDIT: [Here's a screenshot.](http://d.pr/i/ZOgY)

EDIT: Here's my main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int ret = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"ClockApplication", @"ClockApplication");
    [p drain];
    return ret;
}
```

And here's my ClockApplication.mm:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface ClockApplication: UIApplication <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *_window;
    RootViewController *_viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@end

@implementation ClockApplication
@synthesize window = _window;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [_window addSubview:_viewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_viewController release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: I couldn't understand very clear how you want it to be presented... If possible, post some images, even wireframes...

Comment: @CainaSouza I added a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Are you using navigation controller?

Comment: @CainaSouza No, the only UI elements are my root view controller (a UIViewController), and its ivars.

Comment: Have you tired to rotate a device? Maybe it starts in a Portrait mode for some reason.

Comment: @MichalPietras Yes, I've rotated the device, and nothing rotates. Should've mentioned that.

Comment: Try to use debugger or NSLog to check `UIViewController`'s `interfaceOrientation` property after everything is set up.

Comment: @MichalPietras It returned 4, which is landscape left.

Comment: Therefore, you have something messed-up with the view itself. It's rather hard to say what's wrong with this amount of information. Most likely there is something wrong with your view management/drawing code. Try to check size of `UIViewController`'s `view` property. I mean if it is Portrait or Landscape size.

Comment: @MichalPietras It returns {{0, 0}, {480, 320}}, which looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `rootViewController` of your `UIWindow` will receive rotation events.

```
[_window setRootViewController:_rootViewController];
```

Check out [the apple technical notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the simplest way to solve my problems. Any idea why this wasn't the case on iOS 5 (e.g. it worked fine on iOS 5, but not 6)?

Comment: iOS 6 requires rootViewController

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your method from this

```
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIWindow *)window{
}
```

to this

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
}
```

EDIT

Try calling your view inside a navigationcontroller like this:

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
nc.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nc animated:NO];
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

**EDIT**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface ClockApplication: UIApplication <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *_window;
    RootViewController *_viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@end

@implementation ClockApplication
@synthesize window = _window;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
    nc.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    _window.rootViewController = nc;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_viewController release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Sorry, the return is `NSUInteger` and not `NSInteger`

Comment: ALso, set a breakpoint at this method (the new one with this new signature) and check if it's being called.

Comment: It hit the breakpoint, so it's being called. But the issue remains.

Comment: Try what I put in the answer just now

Comment: There is no navigationController property of ClockApplication.

Comment: Then where does `self.navigationController` come from? It's not inherited, is it?

Comment: Oh sorry! Try without that. I edited the answer. It's because I copied from my code but forgot to change it!haha

Comment: Tells me "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target".

Comment: The navigation controller thing fixed it. Thanks a ton for the troubleshooting and for all the help!

Comment: It' rather not a `UINavigationController' thing. You don't need to have it to make it work. Try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
_window.rootViewController = _viewController;
```

EDIT: Anyway your code looks like using "deprecated" style. I would suggest to set up a new project for iOS6 and use its template. It was working on iOS5 but iOS changes.